# How can I set a variable inside a loop without messing up the loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to this, so sorry if this is a daft question.  I have searched for the answer but I can't find a close enough solution to adapt.  This is part of my code:

```
for (var k = 0; k < (pointstoshow.length-1); k++){
   // k looping nicely at this point
u = pointstoshow[k]
   //k not looping at this point, only uses the last number
allpoints[u].setMap(map);
}
```

I am trying to access the numbers inside an array (pointstoshow) to use the number stored as a reference to search another array (allpoints), but I can't get it to work.  If I set an alert to show pointstoshow[k] it works fine, it's only once I try and attach them to a variable it doesn't work.

I've been working on this most of today with no joy, so any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you posted; the comments in the code make no sense, as that last line of code in the loop has no references to `k` at all. Is that *really* the code you're having problems with? Are you doing something like setting up timer handlers or event handlers?

Comment: well of course k will not increment in the second line, the value k will increment after each loop, which means after executing the whole set of instructions between { and }

Comment: I don't really understand what's wrong? So as per your comments you actually get **correct number in `u`** right? So if `u` is correct, why is there even a problem? `allpoints[u]` should be correct too, right? The problems you're describing are usually related to async code (timers or async requests). Is the actual code using any of these?

Comment: Can you post fiddler example? So can understand better.

Comment: Do you know how the for loop works? Read this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: Thanks all, obviously my explanation made more sense in my head than it did on screen.  I have now solved the problem.  Many thanks to Gerrit Brink, it was indeed a missing colon! Simple but true.  Thanks

Comment: Could you post your answer as an answer

Comment: @J.Edwards: This kind of dismissing the community of not getting an actual answer (that may help others in the future) is not really acceptable. Please do provide your own answer (and accept it) or accept an existing one if it solved your problem...

Comment: I'm sorry, I am completely new to this, this is my first ever post.  If you can tell me how to accept an answer I happily will.  No offense was intended, I have just never used this forum before and I am unfamiliar with the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a semi-colon and you need to declare u. Not entirely sure what needs to happen here so this is a shot in the dark.

```
var u;
for(var k = 0; k < (pointstoshow.length-1); k++){  
    u = pointstoshow[k];  
    allpoints[u].setMap(map);  
}
```

Comment: the semicollon is likely just a typo and `u` may as well be (unknowingly) an implied global, but that shouldn't matter in this case...

Comment: To be honest, the (pointstoshow.length-1) also looks a bit dodgy, as it is going to miss one iteration, may have been intended or not, my answer has been down voted. Suppose I will stay away from questions like these in the future.

Comment: Don't worry about downvoting. Let me compensate for that. ;) Some people are just not too good at asking and need some additional questions. It would be better in the future to clear things up a bit using comments on the question than going straight to answers.